# data-src-retina on image tag with .NET Core

Tags: html, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

I am working in a .NET Core 2.0 project. Is there a way to grab the relative image path and pass it to one of the `data-*` attributes?

I have an image like this:

```
<img src="~/images/avatar.jpg" data-src="~/images/avatar.jpg" data-src-retina="~/images/avatar2x.jpg" asp-append-version="true" width="69" height="69" />
```

This doesn't work on high resolution displays because it attempts to grab the static path in `data-src-retina`. This however works

```
<img src="~/images/avatar.jpg" asp-append-version="true" width="69" height="69" />
```

But now I cannot load a high resolution version of the image for retina displays.

Is there a way to pass the relative image path to the `data-*` attributes in .NET Core?

Comment: I don't think `data-src-retina` is a .Net Core or Razor thing (possibly jQuery or a plugin?), that's probably why the `~` prefix doesn't work.

Comment: aye, I know it isn't, but is there a way to pass it the relative image path?

Comment: How about `@Url.Content("~/images/avatar2x.jpg")`?

Comment: Thanks @DavidG, that works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `data-src-retina` isn't a .Net Core or Razor thing, that's why the `~` path prefix doesn't work. Instead you need to convert the string to a relative path. For this, you can use [`Url.Content()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iurlhelper.content?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_IUrlHelper_Content_System_String_) though. For example:

```
<img src="~/images/avatar.jpg" 
     data-src="@Url.Content("~/images/avatar.jpg")" 
     data-src-retina="@Url.Content("~/images/avatar2x.jpg")" 
     asp-append-version="true" width="69" height="69" />
```